# Randomize Array of numbers 1 through 100

Tags: java, arrays, math, random, integer

I'm trying to create a program to create an array of the numbers 1 through 100 and then randomize them. So far I have this, but don't know what to do next:

```
public class Random100Array
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      int[] nums = new int[100];
      char current;
      int a;

      for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
         nums[i] = i + 1;
      }

      for (int i1 = 0; i1 <=nums.length; i1++) {
         double random = (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      }
      }
   }
}
```

Also, THIS ISN'T HOMEWORK. I am a student and I'm currently on winter break. This program gives me this output for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
    at Random100Array.main(Random100Array.java:11)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a random number `nums.length` times and then not doing anything with it? Also, when you say "randomize them", do you mean shuffle the array or choose a new random number for each element?

Comment: do you want to get a permutation of these numbers or just an array of of random numbers from a range?

Comment: @pkacprzak I want to randomize the numbers in the array using the array that I already created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should take care of your for-loops conditions as mentioned in other answers.

Then, for shuffling your input array, you can use this code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] nums = new int[100];

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) 
        {
            nums[i] = i + 1;
        }

        Random generator = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) 
        {           
            int j = generator.nextInt(nums.length - i);         
            int tmp = nums[nums.length - 1 - i];
            nums[nums.length - 1 - i] = nums[j];
            nums[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<` instead of `<=` in your for loops.

Comment: That fixed the problem with the strange output.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing an array with the length of 100 means, you have indices ranging from 0 to 99, so you won't have index 100, thats why you receive this exception. `nums.length` will be 100 (since you initialize the length with 100. Basically your for-loop is ranging from 0 to 100 (which are 101 nums) this is out of bound.

Use `<` instead of `<=` inside the for loops

for shuffeling the array, try something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/995320

Answer (score 0):

You need to use < and not <=

Also, you can use a try catch to escape the exception, but this would not be considered good practice